# SQL Server remote connection working from remote PC localhost but not working from Godaddy plesk hosting

Tags: sql, sql-server, remote-access, plesk, godaddy-api

I am using the following script to connect to a remote SQL Server from my xaamp and it works but when I use the same script in my Godaddy plesk hosting, it's not working.

```
$conn = false;
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = tcp:xx.xx.xx.xx\instancename; Database = dbname", "uname", "password");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }


}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
    die(print_r($e));
}
```

However, on my hosting, I can use this code to connect to local instance (using  but if I change the credential and the hostname to the remote server, it's not working.

this works

```
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "uname", "pwd" => "password", "Database" => "db_second");
$serverName = "tcp:blablabla.shr.prod.iad2.secureserver.net";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


   if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
```

but this doesn't

```
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "uname", "pwd" => "password", "Database" => "dbname");
$serverName = "tcp:xx.xx.xx.xx\instancename";
$conn2 = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn2){
echo "cool" ;
}


   if( $conn2 ) {
     echo "Connection 2 established.<br />";
   }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Whenever you specify `\instancename` in your connection string you need a firewall rule to allow udp/1434 access for the SQL Browser Service to function. This uses the instance name to find the TCP port number that instance is listening on and returns it to the client. If you already know the specific port that instance is listening on you could use something like `tcp:xx.xx.xx.xx,NNNN` instead, where `NNNN` is the port number.

Comment: Still won't connect

Comment: Each hosting provider have their own settings. Please ask your provider about correct connection string that you need to use.